# Rlly - API REST JAVA - NullPointerException when creating new request

Tags: rally

I have tried a example for creating defect from https://developer.help.rallydev.com/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api .

I use rally-rest-api-1.0.7.jar and I set WsapiVersion to 1.33 (my server supports this version).

As a result I get:

```
Creating defect...
Close rest api
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exceptioon
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.attachSecurityInfo(RallyRestApi.java:383)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doSecurityEnableRequest(RallyRestApi.java:360)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doPost(RallyRestApi.java:425)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.create(RallyRestApi.java:169)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.create(RallyRestApi.java:165)
    at com.****.rally.TestCaseResultAppender.newDefect(TestCaseResultAppender.java:43)
    at com.****.rally.TestCaseResultAppenderTest.testNewDefect(TestCaseResultAppenderTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Does anyone also get in trouble with that and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the toolkit is trying to attach some extra security information required for WSAPI version 2.0+ even though you are using 1.x.  I am guessing you may be an on-prem customer and your server does not support the endpoint that the toolkit is trying to use.

This is definitely a defect.  For now does downgrading to 1.0.6 solve the problem?
I'll submit a defect to get this corrected and report back when it is.

You could also simply create a class which extends RallyRestApi and replaces the attachSecurityInfo method with a no-op since this is not required in WSAPI 1.x:

```
public class RallyRestApi1x extends RallyRestApi {
    protected void attachSecurityInfo(HttpRequestBase request) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        //no op
    }
}
```

And then just use this class rather than RallyRestApi.

Comment: i have tried to use version 1.0.6 but it gets the same results. Later today I will try to use this solution.